# Winds in a northern hemisphere hurricane

Tags: meteorology, atmosphere, weather, tropical-cyclone, wind

In the Northern Hemisphere, do surface winds around the center of a hurricane move counterclockwise and inward or counterclockwise and outward?

I'm guessing they move inward.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The winds in a hurricane move cyclonic and inward at the surface and anti-cyclonic and outward in the upper troposphere.

Cyclonic winds are counter-clockwise in the northern hemisphere and clockwise in the southern hemisphere.  Anti-cyclonic is the opposite of cyclonic.

See [this answer](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/a/749/64) for a more detailed discussion of the winds within a tropical cyclone.